# Flutter: Parts of a widget do not show up

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Flutter code sample.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: SideActivityBar()),
        
        // The wiget Text('Initial') does not show up!
        Expanded(flex: 4, child: MainPanel(color: Colors.blue.shade100, page: Text('Initial'))),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class MainPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget page;
  final Color color;
  const MainPanel({Key? key, required this.color, required this.page}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPanel> createState() => _MainPanelState();
}

class _MainPanelState extends State<MainPanel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: widget.color,
      child: widget.page,
    );
  }
}
```

The widget `Text('Initial')` does not show up though I can see `MainPanel` showing up. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What does MainPanel look like? That's probably the issue

Comment: @JoeMuller I've edited to include `MainPanel`.

Comment: I tried your code. I replaced `SideActivityBar` with a Container since I don't have the corresponding code. Everything worked as expected and the Text  `Initial` is also visible

Comment: @quoci, I've switched from Ubuntu (where I've been developing) to Windows and everything works. Thanks.